# Who is the narrator in Rainbow?

Tags: rainbow-nisha-rokubou-no-shichinin

In the anime Rainbow Nisha Rokubou no Shichinin, there is a narrator throughout the series who has the voice of a young female. And in episode 1, she starts the story stating that it all began 50 years ago, implying that she is neither Lily nor Meg. So who is the narrator?

Answer (score -1):

I know this is kinda late and by now you probably have the answer but I thought I should answer it for the sake of other people the narrator is Megumi Hayashibara[image]

Comment: Imo the OP wanted to know the narrator in context of the story itself and not the voice actor who did the job. Lily and Meg being the only prominent female characters.